# ORA-03001: unimplemented feature when converting XMLTYPE to NCLOB from table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

When I try to convert to nclob from XMLTYPE fetched from table, I got error:

> ORA-03001: unimplemented feature

When I try the same for XMLTYPE created on the fly, everything goes fine.

My Oracle version is: **12.1.0.2.0**.

Code example:

This is working correctly:

```
DECLARE
    v_xml XMLTYPE;
    v_clob  CLOB;
    v_nclob nCLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT XMLTYPE('<a>test</a>') INTO v_xml FROM dual;
    v_clob := v_xml.getClobVal();
    v_nclob := to_nclob(v_clob);
END
;
```

This is producing error:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_XMLTYPE_TO_NCLOB
(
      XML_MSG SYS.XMLTYPE
)
;
INSERT INTO TEST_XMLTYPE_TO_NCLOB (XML_MSG) VALUES (XMLTYPE('<a>test</a>'))
;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    v_xml       XMLTYPE;
    v_clob  CLOB;
    v_nclob nCLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT XML_MSG INTO v_xml FROM TEST_XMLTYPE_TO_NCLOB WHERE rownum = 1;
    v_clob := v_xml.getClobVal();
    v_nclob := to_nclob(v_clob);
END
;
```

I would like to know if this is my mistake or oracle bug?

And how can I do conversion from XMLTYPE to NCLOB on data fetched from table in a way that works.

BTW - why cant I catch this exception with WHEN OTHERS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is related to the table storage [using SecureFile storage](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADLOB/adlob_smart.htm#ADLOB46176), which doesn't support or interact with NCLOB. The XMLType you create as part fo the query doesn't use SecureFile (or any) storage, so it isn't affected.

The compiler seems to spot that you're going to be using the SecureFile-stored value - presumably that causes a different flavour of XMLType (I haven't seen this documented, but it seems there might be different internal types you don't normally need to worry about, as with dates; although `dump()` says they are both type 58).

Quite why it complains about you using the CLOB value extracted from it is a bit of a mystery; perhaps the compiler is rewriting the code in a way that means it thinks the XMLType is used more directly. Or perhaps more likely it's a slightly different flavour of CLOB as well/instead. (Based on @BobJarvis' observation, that does seem likely I think.)

It is the compiler throwing the error when you try to manipulate the PL/SQL variable - it's a compile time error, not a run-time exception, which is why you can't catch it.

You can work around it by converting the CLOB back to an XMLType (a different variant now, presumably??) and then back to a CLOB (different variant?) again:

```
DECLARE
    v_xml XMLTYPE;
    v_clob  CLOB;
    v_nclob nCLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT XML_MSG INTO v_xml FROM TEST_XMLTYPE_TO_NCLOB WHERE rownum = 1;
    v_clob := v_xml.getClobVal();
    v_xml := xmltype(v_xml.getClobVal());
    v_clob := v_xml.getClobVal();
    v_nclob := to_nclob(replace(v_clob, chr(10), null));
END
;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Why that works, and why it's necessary, is also a mystery; but suggests different flavours of data type are involved somehow, or at least that's how I interpret it.

It also may not be practical for your real scenario. You can do it as part of the query too:

```
DECLARE
    v_xml XMLTYPE;
    v_clob  CLOB;
    v_nclob nCLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT XMLTYPE(t.XML_MSG.getClobVal()) INTO v_xml
    FROM TEST_XMLTYPE_TO_NCLOB t WHERE rownum = 1;
    v_clob := v_xml.getClobVal();
    v_nclob := to_nclob(replace(v_clob, chr(10), null));
END
;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

which isn't much better but you could perhaps hide it more. Or you could probably also avoid it by explicitly making the XMLType storage CLOB or binary, but that might not be an option or ideal either.

This might be something to raise a service request about with Oracle support. It might be a known bug, but it might be treated as expected behaviour (see also slightly related doc ID 1546992.1).

Comment: Your solution seems to work, and Your explanation makes sense, so I will belive it. ;)
Thank You again, Alex Poole.

Answer (score 2):

As far as **what** is going on:

It appears that when the data written to the XMLTYPE column is read back in and converted to a CLOB, two line-ending sequences (LF/LF) are added to the end. Try printing out the CLOB after it's converted by adding the following after `v_clob := v_xml.getClobVal();`:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_clob=' || v_clob);
```

When the above is run on the CLOB data converted from the XMLTYPE fetched from the database you get

```
<a>test</a>
```

with two linefeeds after it. When you run the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE on the CLOB converted from the in-line XMLTYPE, you get

```
<a>test</a>
```

with NO linefeeds after it.

Now, here's the thing - if you try passing the CLOB which was converted from the XMLTYPE **in the database** to the `TRIM` function you get `ORA-03001: unimplemented feature`. If you pass the CLOB converted from the inline XMLTYPE to the `TRIM` function it works fine. So the problem has nothing to do with `TO_NCLOB` - it appears that it occurs whenever you attempt to use the CLOB which was converted from the XMLTYPE value in the database. I don't know how to work around or fix this.

As far as catching the -30001 exception in a `WHEN OTHERS` - it works fine for me in 11.2g.

Best of luck.

Comment: I think the line feeds are just an artefact of the storage; if you remove those form the PL/SQL CLOB variable it doesn't seem to make any difference. Also you can catch the -30001 if the error it thrown by `trim()` or `to_nclob()` inside the query, but not if it's thrown by a PL/SQL, which is interesting in itself.

Comment: @AlexPoole - my test code caught the exception (in a WHEN OTHERS) when calling `TRIM` in a PL/SQL block.  ???  Also - how did you remove the linefeeds from the CLOB?

Comment: Even more interesting; in PL/SQL you can catch the error from `trim()` at run-time, but not `to_nclob()` - the compiler seems to throw that one. Fun. And I just used `replace(v_clob, chr(10), null)`.